# Subscribe to Meta Newsletter?

Tags: support, feature-request, meta, newsletter

Now that meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange have split, is there a way to subscribe to the newsletter of updates for meta.stackoverflow since my subscription has moved to meta.stackexchange newsletter? It's not obvious to me how or whether this is currently possible.

Comment: i converted this to a feature request because I would like that.

Comment: thank you, i would agree it should be a feature request since it is not possible already

Answer (score 2):

You can't subscribe to Meta Stack Overflow view email newsletters. You can't subscribe to any of the child metas on the other sites either.

What you can do at least is subscribe to the newest questions feed via RSS.

The URL you'll need is: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds